# Trouble creating mysql table with foreign key and referencing it

Tags: php, mysql

I am having trouble getting mysql queries to work between two tables in my database. The tables are as_users (which has user_id and user_name fields) and Test (which has user_id and bio fields).

I am new to foreign keys, but I think I connected these two correctly when I created the Test db like this:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST
(
user_id int NOT NULL,
interests varchar(255) NOT NULL,
bio mediumtext,
PRIMARY KEY (user_id),
FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES as_users(user_id)
)
```

Then in my query I try to pull the 'bio' text from the Test table for the user that is logged in through a session in the as_users table by referencing "user_id".

This is the code, although I have tried it several ways and it hasn't work:

```
$sql    = 'SELECT username FROM as_users WHERE `user_id` = $user_id';
$result = mysql_query($sql, $link);


if (!$result) {
echo "DB Error, could not query the database\n";
echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_error();
exit;
}

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
echo $row['bio'];
}

mysql_free_result($result);
```

So far all I get is "Error, could not query the database MySQL Error:" with no specific error. Not sure if my problem is in my create table code for connecting the tables at user_id or in the sql statement or both...

Comment: what type of connection is `$db`? `$db->select( query, params)` does not look like a standard method for `mysql_query()`, based of you also using `mysql_error()`/`mysql_fetch_assoc()`/`mysql_free_result()`

Comment: It was part of a script I implemented, but I edited above. But nothing works. Thanks for looking anyway...

Comment: which version of php you are using?